# Grouping records from a table

Tags: sql, grouping, oracle12c

Please see the data in this file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gewGZst9zwEzntK9LnwZT4j86rHMVICS/view?usp=sharing

This data represents the recipe for a particular product on a particular date (the product being identified in column pmd_ppm_pr_code and the ingredients in pmd_pi_code).  What I need to do is get the most recent recipe for a particular product.  Here is the SQL I put together to do this;

```
select
    pmd_ppm_sio_reference
    ,pmd_ppm_pr_code
    ,pmd_ppm_date_effective
    ,pmd_percentage
    ,pmd_pi_code
    ,row_number()
    over(partition by pmd_ppm_pr_code, pmd_pi_code
        order by pmd_ppm_pr_code, pmd_pi_code, trunc(pmd_ppm_date_effective) desc) as "row"
from ppm_details
where pmd_ppm_sio_reference = 1801
and pmd_ppm_pr_code = 'A24052'
```

The where clause is just to restrict the results so I can see the wood from the trees.

Here are the results;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mH7n0Q5yQYukJvgR7sh94OsdUaD8sXY_/view?usp=sharing

The issue is with the last item in the group where row = 1.  And that's because that ingredient wasn't used in the latest recipe, but it has given me the latest entry where it was used.

I have tried adding the date into the partition, but all that does is give me row = 1 for every line.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in the question".  Folks are not eager to load files offsite to understand a question.  It is also quite unclear how you identify a "recipe" or "product" in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a column in your data that represents the recipe -- let me just randomly guess that this is `pmd_ppm_pr_code`.  I assume the effective date is the most recent date.  Let me assume that all products in the recipe have the same effective date.

If so, you want to use `dense_rank()`, not `row_number()`:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by pmd_ppm_pr_code order by pmd_ppm_date_effective desc) as seqnum
```

Your version returns the most recent date for each product *separately*.  This returns the most recent by recipe.

Note that your `order by` repeats the partitioning columns.  This is totally unnecessary.  The `order by` is *within* a partition.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon, works perfectly.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, I was convinced I had already done so.  Thanks again.